# Hybris Tenant Activation

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How do I activate a particular tenant in hybris ? As one of my applications operations is throwing "java.lang.IllegalStateException: no tenant active. if you do not want to use tenants, call Registry.activateMasterTenant() to assure the Master tenant is active"

Answer (score 6):

If you are running custom Threads, try putting this in the "run" method:

```
if (!Registry.hasCurrentTenant())
        {
            Registry.activateMasterTenant();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom thread use : TenantAwareThreadFactory. That will create your thread "safety"

Answer (score 0):

If you know what your tenant ID would be then you can use setCurrentTenantByID(String id) on Registry to activate the tenant.

That said, this is probably a bad idea. Usually if hybris is throwing this error it means that something has gone wrong.

Ensure you've got the SessionFilter enabled (this intercepts incoming requests and will set the tenant). Also take a look at what you're doing and make sure you're not spinning off new threads etc which are running outside the scope of the current tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time there is an other exception in the call stack. The "java.lang.IllegalStateException: no tenant active." message is just the last one printed.

If this is not the case, see the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add some JVM options to your classes.

Something like that:

```
 -ea -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dspring.profiles.active=XXX
```

That works for me to run integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

change in the local.properties file.

just the master tenant

```
installed.tenants=
```

just the master tenant along with other tenant

```
installed.tenants="yourparticulartenant"
```

Check if this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think HybrisInitFilter has not been invoked before DispatcherServlet is delegating the request to your controllers. Therefore no tenant has been activated and in turn, most of Hybris platform logic will fail with the error you are seeing.

Please check your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>InitFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>de.hybris.platform.util.HybrisInitFilter</filter-class>
    <!-- GZIP compression of response (default = true) -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>enable.compression</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>tenantIDPattern</param-name>
        <param-value>;\s*tenantID\s*=\s*(\w+)</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>InitFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons for this error,

1. If your system is not initialised.
2. If your application server has lost the DB connection and tenant is deactivated and threads are not able to recover it and set the active tenant .

Solution :

Simply restart the application server, all the threads and session will restore the right value and start working.